# C# Good way to close a form

Tags: c#, forms, design-patterns

Say I want to open a new form..

```
TestForm test = new TestForm();
```

What is the good way to close it? More precisely, is only calling close() ok?
Should I use the using() {} so dispose() is called ? And finally, suppose there is 
a dialog that should have only one instance of a dialog opened, is there a 
well "known" pattern? I've got different choices such as storing it in a static field, 
and null-"ing" it when it is closed..

Thanks

Comment: If it works in context for you, I would suggest to always try and use the using pattern with forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in terms of your single instance dialog (if it's modal you don't have to worry) you can make the constructor private and provide a public static method to access the form.

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    protected MyForm()
    {
    }

    protected int MyValue { get; set; }

    public static int GetResult()
    {
        using(MyForm myForm = new MyForm())
        {
            if(myForm.ShowDialog == DialogResult.OK)
                return myForm.MyValue;   
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

That would force calls to by in the form of..

```
int someValue = MyForm.GetResult();
```

Answer (score 4):

It is good practice to use `using` whenever the object implements `IDisposable`. This will work for a Modal dialog only:

```
using (TestForm test = new TestForm())
{
    ....
}
```

It's syntactically equivalent to a `try{}finally{}` block, so even if an exception is thrown inside the curly braces, `Dispose()` will be called on your object.

Comment: This pattern is great except the window will be useless as it will disappear before anything can be done with it, as it the message loop never spins.

Comment: He is referring to when you use the using pattern and are not showing modal, if you just show the form it's a non blocking call so immediately after the call to Show() the end of the using block is hit and the resources are released.. the form is gone.